# Uninstalling NVM is not successfull

Tags: software-installation, npm

I am newly assigned to take care of a VPS:

```
root@server#lsb_release -a
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
```

I'd like to remove the Node Version Manager `nvm`, but apparently it persists!

I have done the following:

`apt-get remove nvm`

`rm -r /usr/local/nvm`

`rm -r ~/.nvm`

```
root@server:~# whereis nvm
nvm:
root@server:~# which nvm
root@server:~# strace nvm
strace: Can't stat 'nvm': No such file or directory
```

but when I ask for the Version:

```
root@server:~# nvm --version
0.39.7
```

Where is this coming from? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score -1):

I read around about aliases. I stumbled upon this post:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322459/is-it-possible-to-check-where-an-alias-was-defined

So I checked if `nvm` is defined as alias:

```
root@server:~# bash -ixlc : 2>&1 | grep nvm
```

So the following line appeared amon the results:

`. /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh`

In `/etc/profile/nvm.sh` I found this line: `source /opt/nvm/nvm.sh` So that's where it is hidden.

This did the job:

```
root@server:~# rm -r /opt/nvm
root@server:~# rm /etc/profile.d/nvm.sh
```